# reading data from mysql and displaying it in php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to read from my database and display the info in my browser but it shows up a blank page,how do i fix this?

This is my html form:

This is my php script:

```
       // Create connection
       $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
       // Check connection
       if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
       } 

       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM mydb";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);

       if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "name: " . $row["name"]. " - email: " . $row["email"]. " " .  $row["phone"]. "<br>";
       }
       } else {
       echo "0 results";
       }
       }
       $conn->close();
       ?>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: you have value in table??

Comment: Try to change this:  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  to   if(true) {    , maybe you don't pass $_POST[subit] to your php script

Comment: if(isset($_POST["submit"])) to if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")

Comment: first thing is to turn on error_reporting, `ini_set('display_errors', -1)`  blank pages in php are typically a result of syntax errors.  Sometimes even that wont show the error ( if it's all one file ), so you could comment everything out, add an echo in and then progressively un-comment things tell it stops working.  Also you can check the error file, usually this will show up in the directory the script is running in.

Comment: and you are missing the `<?php` ?, probably just from the question, put an echo just before the end to see if the script is completing, then you can backtrack why the other echos are not outputting anything.